# How do I call a static Java method from Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle build script which currently works by simply executing a Java class through it's main method. What I want to know is, how can I call a static method in the same class but not have to go through the main method. The current gradle code is as follows:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
apply plugin: 'java'

defaultTasks 'runSimple'

project.ext.set("artifactId", "test-java")

File rootDir = project.getProjectDir()
File targetDir = file("${rootDir}/target")
FileCollection javaClasspath = files("${targetDir}/tools.jar")

task(runSimple, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.test.model.JavaTest'
    classpath = javaClasspath
    args 'arg1'
    args 'arg2'
}
```

And my Java class as follows:

```
package com.test.model;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In main");
        anotherMethod(args[0], args[1]);
    }

    public static void anotherMethod(String arg1, String arg2) {
        System.out.println("In anotherMethod");
        System.out.println(arg1 + " " + arg2);
    }
}
```

This gives me the output:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:runSimple
In main
In anotherMethod
arg1 arg2

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.344 secs
```

My question is simply how can I skip the main method, and call the method "anotherMethod" directly from the gradle script? The output would then simply be:

```
In anotherMethod
arg1 arg2
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to run in the context (i.e. the classloader) of the Gradle build, or as a separate process? The `JavaExec` task works just like calling the `java` command from a shell. It will always execute the `main` method.

Comment: I would ideally like it to run as a separate process. Is there any way to achieve this in Gradle? Furthemore, this Java method will be called upon many times during the execution of the Gradle script. Therefore I would like it to not spin up a new JVM every time it makes a call to the same Java method, and run within the same JVM. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hmm... If you want it to be a separate process that you can call repeatedly using the same process, it seems more like a daemon or service. Gradle's `JavaExec` merely supports the equivalent of calling the `java` command from the shell. That is, it will run the main method of the class you specify **once**. Gradle can run any Groovy code you want, so I'm sure that it is possible to do this, but I don't see any straightforward way.

Comment: Why don't you make a Bootstrap class with a main method that calls your static method that needs to execute several times? This way you only have one JVM running your code.

Answer (score 3):

you have to add the jar or class to the classpath. here is an example with a jar file who contains the class. 
Inside the file build.gradle add the dependencies.
My jar file is in the `lib` folder the path is `lib/MQMonitor.jar`.

```
import mypackage.MyClass
buildscript {
   repositories {
      flatDir name: 'localRepository', dirs: 'lib'
   }
    dependencies {
        classpath name: 'MQMonitor'
    }
}

task myTaskCallJava << {
   MyClass.foo()
}
```

Comment: `<<` is deprecated; should use `doLast`

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this too. You know I like the function of eclipse and intellij with the run with Junit options, and I want to do this using command line and gradle.

If you could accept putting your test method in the directory of 'test' directory of gradle. I actually have a fair solution.

```
package com.udacity.gradle;
import org.junit.Test;

    public class TestClass {
        @Test
        public void anotherMethod() {
            System.out.println("This is it, I want this!!!");
        }
        @Test
        public void notMyWantedMethod1() {

            System.out.println("not my wanted");
        }

        public void notMyWantedMethod2() {
            System.out.println("not my wanted");
        }

    }
```

This my test class which is in **src/test/java/com/udacity/gradle/TestClass.java**

Then the under below is the file of my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "java"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}


test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    filter {
        //include specific method in any of the tests
        includeTestsMatching "*.TestClass.anotherMethod"
    }
}
```

Simple idea you know this is a test class so I use the test task of gradle. And to specify which method to use, I added a Test filter which could specify down to method.

Then you could just run

```
gradle test
```

Then you could find in console that you have what you want in there. However, remember to add

```
testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
```

if you don't do this, gradle would swallow your console output. But even if you don't add this line. You could read a test log in the directory of

...../build/test-results/test/TEST-com.udacity.gradle.TestClass.xml

There are well organized test reports output in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="com.udacity.gradle.TestClass" tests="1" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0" timestamp="2018-03-31T19:26:44" hostname="hexin-PC" time="0.022">
  <properties/>
  <testcase name="anotherMethod" classname="com.udacity.gradle.TestClass" time="0.022"/>
  <system-out><![CDATA[This is it, I want this!!!
]]></system-out>
  <system-err><![CDATA[]]></system-err>
</testsuite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the class is on the buildscript classpath (it should be, since you're calling `main` from the same class)

```
task runSimple {
  doLast {
    com.test.model.JavaTest.anotherMethod("foo", "bar")
  }
}
```

Tested on Gradle 4.6

Answer (score -2):

If you want to execute a static method you will need to add the class to the Gradle build script's classpath.

To add the code to the build scripts classpath if your code is in a repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "${yourRepositoryURL}" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.yourgroup:yourpackagename:version'
    }
}
```

To add the code to the build scripts classpath if you code is built locally (I didn't test this one):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files("path/to/where/the/class/files/are")
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to call that method just like any other:

```
task runSimple(dependsOn: 'classes') {
    doFirst() {
        com.test.model.JavaTest.anotherMethod('arg1', 'arg2')
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah.. this doesn't work at all.. and I still can't figure out an elegant way to do this.. I don't want to have to create a class for a single line of Java