# Read static Java class from build.gradle file

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I want to read few properties from a static java class file as below

```
class MyClass {
      public static final class MyStaticClass {
         public static final String PROPERTY_A = "myStringA";
         public static final String PROPERTY_B = "myStringB";
      }
}
```

This would be in MyClass.java file under

> src/main/java/myProject/

I need to read `PROPERTY_A`, and `PROPERTY_B` in my app build.gradle inside android{} block.

Note that these need to be read from java file for a specific reason, and are not general properties. Hence, I am not reading them from `gradle.properties` files.

I went through [How do I call a static Java method from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590581/how-do-i-call-a-static-java-method-from-gradle)

but the article wasn't super clear.

I also tried gradle docs, but couldn't find a super clear answer.

I am bit new to groovy, so any suggestions here would be super helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: curious.. why do this? Why not just have a property file and then pull those values from there into build.gradle? I think information is supposed to flow from the build config into the application, not the other way around.

Comment: There is a restriction to use the properties from this java file

Comment: That does not change the technological constraints.

Comment: You can try using `BuildConfigField` but this will be the opposite way for you . FYI  I have the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874250/use-a-java-class-in-build-gradle)  a while ago but did not get any answer . Looks like its not technological possible .

Comment: Thanjs @ADM I will try my luck for couple of hours before returning to use custom properties file

Comment: in what part if the lifecycle do you need this: https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it sounds like It's not possible in the initialization part of gradle build to read static java classes from the answers so far. 
I decided to read it via .properties file eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Find out when in the [lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) that the code in the android {} gets executed. Worst case this will be early, so you may have to compile that class before anything else. Then write some groovy code in your gradle script to get the properties.