# Local verification of avro schema validity and compatibility

Tags: gradle, avro

We're using `avro` for (de)serialization of messages that flow through a message broker. For the purpose of storing the avro files a schema registry ([apicurio](https://www.apicur.io/registry/)) is used. This provides two benefits - schema validation and compatibility validation. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to go around the schema registry and achieve the same locally, using a script/plugin. Validating if an avro file is syntactically/semantically valid should be possible. The same applies for compatibility validation, as checking if a new schema version is backward/forward compatible against a list of other schemas (the previous versions) also sounds doable locally.

Is there a library that does that? Ideally a gradle plugin, but a java/python library would do as well, as it can easily be called from a gradle task.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is confluent's Java class for checking schema compatibility within its schema registry:

- https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/core/src/test/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/avro/AvroCompatibilityTest.java

You can use it to validate schemas locally.

Expedia has used it as a basis to create their own compatibility tool:

- https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/avro-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a plugin doing just that what you ask for. Plugins seem to aim for generating classes from the schema files (i.e. https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin). Without getting into **why** you want to do this, I think you could use this simple approach ([How do I call a static Java method from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590581/how-do-i-call-a-static-java-method-from-gradle)) to hook you custom code into Gradle and checking for schema validity and compatibility.

Refer to following Avro Java API:

- https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaCompatibility.html
- https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaValidatorBuilder.html

Also checking this particular class can be helpful for executing validation against the schema:

- https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/tool/DataFileReadTool.java